# Including file inside a class php

Tags: php, class

I am doing something using classes in php for very first time.
I am trying to fetch an `return object array` items in class.

This is my class

```
class User {

    $dbconn = include("config.php");
    private $dbHost     = $dbconn->host;
    private $dbUsername = $dbconn->username;
    private $dbPassword = $dbconn->pass;
    private $dbName     = $dbconn->database;
    private $userTbl    = 'users';

    function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->db)){
            // Connect to the database
            $conn = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }else{
                $this->db = $conn;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `config.php` file

```
return (object) array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'my_user',
    'pass' => 'my_pass',
    'database' => 'my_db'
);
```

How do i do it?

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$dbconn' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Comment: why do you have this? $dbconn = include("config.php");

Comment: Include the file before the class.

Comment: @RavinderReddy i already tried that. PhpDev what do you mean? I am including host, username, pass, database from file. But that doesn't work in class.

Comment: I just want to thank everyone for various answers which were very helpful to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can't have executable code in a variable definition, only static values. So this sort of thing is not supported:

```
class foo {
    public $var = result_of_some_function();
}
```

If you want to initialize a value, use the constructor. You're probably better off reading it as a config file:

```
class User {
    public function __construct() {
        $config = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json'));
        $conn = new mysqli($config->host, ...);
    }
}
```

Or better, using dependency injection:

```
class User {
    protected $db = null;
    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Then in your code that creates a user object:

```
$db = new Db($config);
$user = new User($db);
```

Answer (score 3):

The other way is to define constants in config file and use them in class.

in config.php file

```
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USERNAME', 'my_user');
define('PASS', 'my_pass');
define('DATABASE', 'my_db');
```

In class file

```
include("config.php")
class User {
    private $dbHost     = HOST;
    private $dbUsername = USERNAME;
    private $dbPassword = PASS;
    private $dbName     = DATABASE;
    private $userTbl    = 'users';

    function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->db)){
            // Connect to the database
            $conn = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }else{
                $this->db = $conn;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Include this:

```
 $dbconn = include("config.php");
```

in your construct function.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should change in your code to

```
function __construct()
    {
        //included db file
        include 'config.php'; 
        if (!isset($this->db))
        { 
//code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way of using it.

```
<?php
class User
{

    private $dbconn = null;
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbUsername;
    private $dbPassword;
    private $dbName;
    private $userTbl = 'users';

    function __construct()
    {
        include 'config.php'; //included file in constructor
        if (!isset($this->db))
        {
            $this->dbHost= $this->dbconn->host;
            $this->dbUsername= $this->dbconn->username;
            $this->dbPassword= $this->dbconn->pass;
            $this->dbName= $this->dbconn->database;
            // Connect to the database
            $conn = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);
            if ($conn->connect_error)
            {
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } else
            {
                $this->db = $conn;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Config.php**

```
<?php
$this->dbconn= (object) array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'my_user',
    'pass' => 'my_pass',
    'database' => 'my_db'
);
```

Comment: This answer i like the best, thanks, i'll try it now

Comment: @Darktwen Welcome try it... :) and let me know is it working fine?

Comment: There's no sense setting host, user, pass, and dbname variables on the object if you're making the connection inside the constructor.

Comment: I can call it right away with $this->dbconn->database without defining it above, i got that.

Comment: Might be. but what i did i answered the question in the way OP wants.

Comment: @Darktwen you have to define it.

Comment: U do not understand, this is what i did...
`$conn = new mysqli($this->dbconn->host, $this->dbconn->username, $this->dbconn->pass, $this->dbconn->database);`

Comment: You can also remove the `if (!isset($this->db))` check as it will always be true.